# is it possible to use LogonUser API without password?

Tags: c++, windows, impersonation

I am developing a c++ application and this application runs as a windows service.
I need to impersonate the current user to access the network location and for this I am using Windows API `LogonUser` and `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`.

The problem is that I only have username and domain information but not the password. So is it possible to call the `LogonUser` without providing the password to get the user handle?

Comment: What is _the current user_ for a Windows Service? Windows Services run under their own user account, which is independent from the interactive user(s). (Comment because you apparently have a real user name)

Comment: service runs as a system user, and if I try to get username it is showing `system` as user.

Comment: That's indeed a common account for services. `SYSTEM` by design has no accces to protected network resources.

Comment: @MSalters: you're thinking of LOCAL SERVICE.  The SYSTEM account can access the network, using the computer's domain account.  (But only if it is joined to a domain, obviously.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that would be a rather obvious security leak.

You may however use a named pipe between a UI process for the current user and your service. Your service can then impersonate the other side of the named pipe. This is secure because you control both ends of the pipe.